# Using BytesIO as stdout/stderr target for subprocess.run

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to run a subprocess and redirect the stdout and stderr to different targets. The `subprocess.run` method allows for both capturing the output in memory (with argument `capture=True`) or redirecting into a file by providing file-like values to arguments `stdout` and `stderr`. I need to redirect `stdout` directly into a file, but want to capture `stderr` so I can give the errors to the logging system. I thought that `BytesIO` would be perfect for capturing as a file-like target and then processing the content from this. However when I run this code:

```py
temp_file_like = BytesIO(b'')
subprocess.run(
    arguments, check=True, shell=False,
    stdout=target_file_handle, stderr=temp_file_like
)
for line in str(temp_file_like.getvalue()).split("\n"):
    logger.warning(line)
```

(Code is simplified)

I get the error:

```
File "C:\path\to\script.py", line 143, in run_with_redirect
    stdout=target_file_handle, stderr=temp_file_like
File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 488, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 753, in __init__
    errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1106, in _get_handles
    errwrite = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(stderr.fileno())
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

It seems to me that while `subprocess.run` is supposed to accept file handles, a `BytesIO` instance is not sufficiently file-like to be accepted as target. Is there a way to capture only of the streams while redirecting the other into a file, without having to use a temporary file on disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you should use subprocess.PIPE for stdout while still having stderr pointing to the temp file handle and then just capture stdout via proc.stdout.read():

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    arguments,
    check=True,
    shell=False,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=temp_file_like
)
output = proc.stdout.read()
```

Comment: Note: It's the other way around, in that I'm using the proper file handle for ```stdout``` and now capture ```stderr``` with ```PIPE```, but this answer solved my problem. Thank you!